# How to Upload images even when the app is killed in android

Tags: android, intentservice, background-service

I'm calling upload images api, in `IntentService` which is running in the background and upload the images to server.

IntentService, `onHandleEvent` method is called and run in the background, what I understand is `IntentService` will execute the task and calls `stopSelf()` method.

In my app when uploading is in progress when I kill my app, the upload is terminated and `IntentService` stopped witch out completing the upload task.

***how can I make my `IntentService` run even when the app is killed?***

Edit 1: I tried using Sticky service, when I kill the app the service restarted and Intent data passed to the `onStartCommand` method is null

Comment: use sticky service

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code. First of all you need to add properties of Service in Manifest file

```
<service
        android:name=".service.Service"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:isolatedProcess="true">

  </service>
```

And also add `START_STICKY` in your service.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service as mentioned in below step to keep the service running all the time

1) In the service onStartCommand method return START_STICKY.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
return START_STICKY;
}
```

2)Start the service in the background using startService(MyService) so that it always stays active regardless of the number of bound clients.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PowerMeterService.class);
startService(intent);
```

3)Create the binder.

```
public class MyBinder extends Binder {
public MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
}
}
```

4)Define a service connection.

```
private ServiceConnection m_serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        m_service = ((MyService.MyBinder)service).getService();
}

public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        m_service = null;
}
};
```

5)Bind to the service using bindService.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
bindService(intent, m_serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: Start sticky, will it send intent data to service once I kill the app? how it will restart the service?